# Apostrophe in Product Name not working in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm developing a site in magento CE 1.8. I have some products which have apostrophe (') sign in their names like ABC's. Problem is, I can't add these specific products to the cart as nothing is happening when I click the add to cart button.
Is there any solution for this problem as when I searched through google, I couldn't find one.
Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If its a single quotation mark (ie not an apostrophe), try escape the `'` char: `\'`.

Comment: I imported product names from CSV file, and using the default add to cart mechanism. Where should I do as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure how magneto works, cause I have never used it, but you could try the `addslashes($s)` function right before adding it to chart (http://www.php.net/addslashes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName());
```

or

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
```